# restrict number of items obtained from python generator

Tags: python, python-2.7, generator

Is there a neater way than following to restrict number of items from a generator?

```
def next_dummy_item():
    for i in range(1, 10):
        yield i

item_count = 0
for item in next_dummy_item(): # can't use slicing here :(
  item_count += 1             
  # process item
  if item_count > 5:
    break
```

Comment: @200 OK thanks but I couldn't search it. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
def next_dummy_item():
    for i in range(1, 10):
        yield i

for item in itertools.islice(next_dummy_item(), 5):
    # process item
```